# Triggers x PHP Controller

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I need to do something like that:
I have a heavy processing method, and my customer access much times the part of site that execute that heavy method. So I think a way to doesn't execute every time this heavy method.

What's my solution? I'll save the values of the first run of this heavy method, and use this already processed value while there are no changes to make the method run again.

So, for example. I have a "product broken counter" aways my customer access the main page, the system says to him "you have X products broken", when my customer change something on product, i'll change a flag on my database, and this flag say to me "Run the heavy method again to calculate this".

This is the case, now my doubt, its better use trigger to say "when table product has change, update the flag to false", or do it on PHP?

If i choose to use a trigger, what is the proccess/database/memmory/bandwith cost?

I read triggers are bad becouse have low maintainability, and is hard to new programers to find where is this function. But it'll never change, not soon. And i have many places on code to change the product and turn the flag off.

So i know php is better on many ways, but its harder to implement.

What you guys can tell me?

Comment: @DamienPirsy hi, thanks for the interest. Becouse i need to global context, this functions are some kind of "alert" and have many other situations. And i need it to all users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with triggers. Although they might a pain in the neck sometimes they allow to centralize the code and separate it from application logic meaning no matter how a product is changed the db will flag it for processing.

That being said the a possible overall highlevel processing flow might be as follows:

1. `AFTER UPDATE` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) flags products that have been changed inserting product_id to special table `flagged_products`
2. A stored procedure (let's call it `sp_process_flagged_products`) on demand (when user clicks on a button) or periodically (e.g. once a day), using [mysql events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) or cron, processes flagged products and clears processed products from `flagged_products` table.

Now a trigger tracking changes to products might be as simple as

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_update
AFTER UPDATE ON products
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT IGNORE INTO flagged_products (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.product_id);
```

> *...and is hard to new programers to find where is this function...*

To list all triggers in your database use [`SHOW TRIGGERS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-triggers.html)

```sql
SHOW TRIGGERS
-- LIKE '%product%'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85336/6)** demo.